# grub-install failure (fatal error)

Tags: grub2

I am trying to install ubuntu 12.04 from a usb side by side with windows 7.
My hard drive already had 3 partitions by window:

- sda1 (1.8GB) for system
- sda2 (700 GB) for windows
- sda3(16GB) for windows recovery.

  I shrunk windows partition to 200GB and made a new extended partition within which sda5 (10GB) is `linux-swap` and rest is sda6 for linux(ext4). The installation runs fine until the end when it says "grub-install dev/sda6 failed. I tried to give it an option to install grub in dev/sda but it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: could you check whether the disk is configured as basic or dynamic ? run `diskmgmt.msc` in windows and look below the disk name (`Disk 0`). [Some information will look like `Disk 0` `Basic` `990GB` `Online`]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry, I am at work right now and can't get on my laptop until the evening!! I will post these info asap.

Comment: Did you try the grub-install on dev/sda2 in your case? What's in sda1? "for system" what does it means?

Comment: You may be experincing this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/976027

Comment: @JulienChau sda1 is possibly created by windows 7 to accommodate windows recovery environment.It contains windows boot manager.  installing @ sda2 will fail as well.

Comment: @ Web-E diskmgmt.msc shows that all the partitions are basic

Comment: @ Julien Chau None of the partition works for grub-install

Comment: Thank you all. I deleted the partition that Ubunut was installed in, redid the partitioning, reinstalled the Ubuntu. This time instead of choosing the recommended option to "install side by side with windows", I chose the third option to do the partition myself. Chose /dev/sda for grub-install. The installation was seamless. I booted to both windows and linux few times with no difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [in comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146844/grub-install-failure-fatal-error#comment177371_146844)

> I deleted the partition that Ubuntu was installed in, redid the
>   partitioning, reinstalled the Ubuntu. This time instead of choosing
>   the recommended option to "install side by side with windows", I chose
>   the third option to do the partition myself.
>
> Chose `/dev/sda` for grub-install. The installation was seamless. I
>   booted to both windows and linux few times with no difficulty.

Comment: Your problem is solved. If you have more problems with the grub, download grub-repair, and burn it on a disc.  It may be useful in case of... .  You can always boot with this CD, and automatically repair the boot section.http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair/?source=directory

Comment: I had the same damn problem too when clicking 'install side by side'. I knew I should've configured it myself -_-